# Não consigo obter o elemento Selected de DropDownListFor dentro de uma PartialView para enviar para o Controller via ActionLink

Tags: html, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Olá

Tenho uma PartialView que é preenchida com registos seleccionados através de filtros anteriores. A partial view não é mais do que a apresentação de uma tabela com varias linhas em que cada linha será um registo e terá uma DropDownListFor e um button actualizar em cada uma dessas linhas/registo.

O objectivo é poder actualizar o campo através da dropdownlistfor e depois gravar na bd com o button actualizar.

Aqui fica o código da partial_view:

```
<table id="table" class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Descrição</th>
            <th>Início</th>
            <th>Fim</th>
            <th>Origem</th>
            <th>Estado</th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        @if (Model.listGestaoAfericoes != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in Model.listGestaoAfericoes)
            {

                <tr id="@item.id">
                    <td id="id">@item.id</td>
                    <td>@item.descricao</td>
                    <td>@item.data_ini_afericao</td>
                    <td>@item.data_fim_afericao</td>
                    <td id="origem">@item.origem_afericao</td>
                    <td>@item.id_estado_actual</td>

                    <td>Estado: @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedEstadoRow, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)Model.listEstados, "Seleccione um Estado")</td>
                    <td>

                        @Html.ActionLink("Alterar Estado", "AlterarEstadoAfericao", new { item.id, @Model.SelectedEstadoRow },
    new { onclick = "return confirm('Tem a certeza que pretende alterar o estado?');", @class = "btn btn-info" })

                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        }

    </table>
```

Aqui fica o codigo do controller:

```
 public ActionResult AlterarEstadoAfericao(int id, string SelectedEstadoRow)
 {

 }
```

O que acontece é que o valor selectedEstadosRow passa sempre a null para o controller e não recolhe o valor (String tipo de estado) da dropdownlistfor. Sendo esta dropdownlistfor preenchida correctamente por uns 10 elementos.

Alguém me sabe como ajudar a obter o registo especifico seleccionado pela dropdownlistfor de cada row e subter esse registo no momento do click no ActionLink?

Cumprimentos

Comment: O `DropDownListFor` assim como o `ActionLink` são renderizados no lado do servidor, antes do usuário fazer a sua seleção.  Você vai precisar fazer um post para a controller ou montar esse link manualmente capturando a informação via `JavaScript`

Comment: Certo no entanto a questão que me refiro é que model.SelectedEstadoRow supostamente obtido pelo DropDownListfor é Null quando inserido no ActionLink @Model.SelectedEstadoRow

Comment: De que forma seria mais facil executar esta acção? Podes dar-me um exemplo? Quer via Post quer via JavaScript?

Comment: Ele é null porque ele é executando antes de o controle ser rederizado na tela

Comment: Já estou a conseguir passar o ViewModel, no entanto preciso preencher um campo "idSelected" do ViewModel com o valor do @item.id, como poderei fazer isso na view? Não estou a conseguir

Comment: Ou melhor eu consigo enviar o id, mas quando a tabela tem mais do que 1 linha o item.id leva o id do primeiro elemento da linha ao invés do id da linha correspondente a alteração...

Comment: Isso é outro problema completamente diferente

Comment: E tem alguma ideia de como me ajudar a resolver esse problema?

Comment: Depende, o que faz o método  `AlterarEstadoAfericao(int id, string SelectedEstadoRow)`?

Comment: Eu alterei esse metodo para public ActionResult AlterarEstadoAfericao(GestaoAfericoesViewModel model), sendo que esse metodo depois irá alterar campos na base de dados com dados provenientes desse model, seja o id de cada row, e o respectivo estado seleccionado na dropdownlist

Comment: nesse caso você vai ter que postar a ViewModel para ele